# DbContext ExecuteSqlRaw missing parameters error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have this code for executing stored procedure:

```
var result = await DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
                "Get_FlightBooking @BookingReferenceNumber, @BM_BKDTFOM, @BM_BKDTTO, @User_Id",
                new SqlParameter("@BookingReferenceNumber", model.BookingId == string.Empty ? null : model.BookingId),
                new SqlParameter("@BM_BKDTFOM", model.FromDt == string.Empty ? null : model.FromDt),
                new SqlParameter("@BM_BKDTTO", model.FromDt == string.Empty ? null : model.FromDt),
                new SqlParameter("@User_Id", model.UserId));
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[Get_FlightBooking]
(

 @BookingReferenceNumber   VARCHAR(50)=NULL,   
 @BM_BKDTFOM  VARCHAR(50)=NULL,  
 @BM_BKDTTO   VARCHAR(50)=NULL,  
 @User_Id  bigint=null
)
as
begin
    SELECT distinct BookingID,
            BookingReferenceNumber,
            Sector,
            AirlineCode,
            AirlineName,
    FROM dbo.Flights AS fb  
    WHERE (fb.BookingReferenceNumber=@BookingReferenceNumber OR @BookingReferenceNumber IS NULL)   
         AND((CAST(fb.BookingDate AS DATE)>= CAST(@BM_BKDTFOM AS DATE) OR @BM_BKDTFOM IS NULL) AND (CAST(fb.BookingDate AS DATE)<=CAST(@BM_BKDTTO AS DATE) OR @BM_BKDTTO IS NULL))  
         AND (fb.UserId=@User_Id or @User_Id=1)
END
```

Is anyone seeing something wrong in the way how the stored procedure is being executed? When calling the C# code I'm getting this error:

> The parameterized query '(@BookingReferenceNumber
> nvarchar(4000),@BM_BKDTFOM nvarchar(400' expects the parameter
> '@BookingReferenceNumber', which was not supplied.

Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DBNull.Value` and not `null`

```
var result = await DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
            "UspGet_FlightBooking @BookingReferenceNumber, @BM_BKDTFOM, @BM_BKDTTO, @User_Id",
            new SqlParameter("@BookingReferenceNumber", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.BookingId) ? DNNull.Value : model.BookingId),
            new SqlParameter("@BM_BKDTFOM", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.FromDt) ? DNNull.Value : model.FromDt),
            new SqlParameter("@BM_BKDTTO", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.FromDt) ? DNNull.Value : model.FromDt),
            new SqlParameter("@User_Id", model.UserId));
```

If you cant use C# 9.0 maybe try initialising your SqlParameters like this:

```
 new SqlParameter("@BookingReferenceNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000)
            { Value = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.BookingId) ? (object)DBNull.Value : model.BookingId }
```

Comment: I tried that already but getting "Feature 'target-typed conditional expression' is not available in C# 8.0. Please use language version 9.0 or greater."